# Super strange PHP error

Tags: php, memcached

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cannot store values into memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107398/cannot-store-values-into-memcache)

Hi everyone,

When trying memcache:get, I'll get the following error message back:

```
Message: Memcache::get() [memcache.get]: Server localhost (tcp 11211) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0)
```

I run a Windows 32bit test environment (XP) and here's how my code looks:

```
 function getMulti(array $keys) {
      $items = $this->memcache->get($keys);
      return $items;
 }
```

My memcache servers are two local computers in the LAN that my dev. environment is connected to.

Sure, I can turn the error logging off or just put an @ before the get function call, but that doesnt solve this issue. What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107398/cannot-store-values-into-memcache

Comment: Which version of PECL/Memcache are you running?

Comment: Did you try to use the possible solution the the duplicate that *@ax* reported? I see that you commented there, but have you actually tried to implement that solution?

Comment: Well, the strange thing is that this does not occur every time, but only when the requested key is non-existent in the memcache storage

Comment: I can also connect to memcache with telnet, however it returns a blank black page in the command prompt of xp