# Memcache connects but doesn't respond to any command

Tags: php, memcached, ascii, sasl

**Setup:**
Apache; PHP 5.2.9; libevent (for memcached it's required) version 1.3; memcached server version 1.2.2 (tried 1.4.5, 1.4.0, now downgraded to 1.2.2, no difference); memcached php pecl module version 2.2.6.

**Problem:**

Similar to unresolved problems [cannot store values into memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107398/cannot-store-values-into-memcache) and [Super strange PHP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872928/super-strange-php-error)

None of those threads had resolved issue and none of the authors of questions followed recommendations given. I followed them all, and it still doesn't work.

`Memcache` code doesn't show any error if I am connecting via PHP, but as soon as I'm trying to execute any command (such as `getVersion`), I get the response:

`Notice: memcache_get_version() [function.memcache-get-version]: Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0) in /var/www/html/memcache.php on line 11`

**Solutions tried:**

Connecting to memcache via command line is not working. After I type any command connection is closing.

```
[/usr/local/src]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried `$ memcached -S` to make sure memcached was compiled with SASL support disabled.
Response: "This server is not built with SASL support."

Also, one of the comments was

> You may be running memcached without ASCII protocol support, such as if you ran:
>
> ```
>  $ memcached -B binary
> ```
>
> If this is the case, remove the `-B` argument entirely, and PHP and telnet should work.

The memcache start line is:

```
memcached -d -m 1024 -u root -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211
```

No B argument in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

To whom it might be interesting.

Issue resolved.

Here is where problem was(maybe it would help authors from 2 related treads).

On shared hosting sometimes you shouldn't use 127.0.0.1. Instead, use site's IP address.

So changing

```
memcached -d -m 1024 -u root -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211
```

to

```
memcached -d -m 1024 -u root -l 123.456.789.123 -p 11211
```

and PHP code from

```
$memcache->pconnect("127.0.0.1",11211);
```

to

```
$memcache->pconnect("123.456.789.123",11211);
```

fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, if you found an answer that solves your problem (such as this) please **accept** it. It's easy, just click the green **tick** at the votes area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would talk to your sys sadmin.  I think the there maybe a firewall involved.

Comment: And what might it block? I mean if connect goes through, it can't be blocking 11211 port, right?