# PHP memcache problem

Tags: php, windows, memcached, telnet

I am trying to set up memcache server on my localhost. Now before you jump on with me duplicates here is a list of them.

Duplicates:

1. [Memcache connects but doesn't respond to any command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045187/memcache-connects-but-doesnt-respond-to-any-command)
2. [cannot store values into memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107398/cannot-store-values-into-memcache)
3. [Super strange PHP error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872928/super-strange-php-error)

**However** none of them solves my problem or it just isnt followed anymore. One comment mentiones my telnet issue, but there is no reply to it.

This is the setup:

1. Xampp 1.7.4 (VC6)
2. memcache 2.2.5
3. memcached 1.2.6 (tried with memcache from 1.2.1-1.4.5 same - problem)

I have followed this and many more tutorials http://www.leonardaustin.com/technical/how-to-install-memcached-on-xampp-on-windows-7. Memcached server is running as service, I can connect fine to it, but any command I use ends with the same error:

```
Notice: Memcache::getversion() [memcache.getversion]: Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211) failed with: Failed reading line from stream (0)
```

So I went to check up with telnet if it works. Any command I enter or anything for that matter will return me back to command line without any indication whats going on. There is no log supplied with memcached or any mention in windows event viewer. If I try to use putty and log it, there is nothing in the log except the `stats` command I typed.

I tried to set it up to like 20 different ports. `netstat` tells me it is listening on that port (tcp and udp). Firewall is disabled.

I have really no idea whats going on here and I am about to cry :( **ANY** kind of advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how to fix your problem...sorry :(... but try this class check if it works, the commands are same as memcached (and its memcached not memcache you have append and such stuff) but it uses the socket to connect to memcahed so its not complied with php its a lil bit slower.

https://github.com/pompo500/xslib-memcached/blob/master/xslib-memcached.php

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in memcached.exe then. Can you confirm that memcached is running? You can test it by executing this on the console:

wmic process get description, executablepath | findstr memcached.exe